# How can I stop/debug IE11's weird behavior with combo-loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We combo-load our javascript files using `YUI3`'s loader. Essentially, this makes requests of the following form:

```
[our domain]/app/combo?file/path/1.js&file/path/2.js&...
```

where the combo endpoint returns the given path as a combined javascript file. We are now hitting issues with this in IE11 only, where IE will sometimes fail to load one of these requests. In the network tab of the dev tools there is sometimes one or two of these requests listed as aborted. When I copy that request's URL to a browser tab, it sometimes offers me a run/save download option (complaining about an unverified publisher) and sometimes fails outright complaining about my security settings.

Other times, I don't see an aborted request but instead I see a request with a result status code of 0. The request has a blank headers page and is listed as containing 0 bytes, but in the response body tab I see some of the expected content (it's truncated).

How can I fix or at least debug this issue?

Comment: Can you export the request/response headers for these failing requests? If you'd like more granular detail, download http://fiddler2.com and inspect the sessions with it.